# Does setting requiressl = true have any impact on loadbalancer or F5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, adfs2.0

I have a web application which is using ADFS for authentication process. While implementing the CSRF to the application, I came across the url: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages which says that setting requiressl=true is good prevention.

Currently the application has the following in web.config:

```
<microsoft.identityModel>   
      <federatedAuthentication>        
        <cookieHandler requireSsl="false" />
      </federatedAuthentication>
```

As per the article mentioned above I have set requireSsl=true.

Can anyone help me to know is there any impact or any known issues at loadbalacer or F5 level with this setting?

Comment: With the above change I came across an ADFS error:ID1059: Cannot authenticate the user because the URL scheme is not https and requireSsl is set to true in the configuration, therefore the authentication cookie will not be sent. Change the URL scheme to https or set requireSsl to false on the cookieHandler element in configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting SSL Setting at the website level with RequireSSL checked with Ignore as the option helped me to resolve the issue.